# Can powering a DC motor through the USB ports of my Raspberry Pi Damage the Pi?

Tags: pi-2, usb-power, dc-motor

I'm working on a project that contains two DC motors and a Raspberry Pi, I do not have other components like Relay, Motor Drivers, transistors etc. I am aware that powering a motor directly from an output pin can damage the Pi, but I was able to power the motors using the USB ports of the Pi. The question being, can that cause damage to my Pi.

Note : I am aware that this is not a very efficient way to do things, But I can't get additional components because of a total lockdown in my city